# Nothing to migrate in Laravel Backpack Package [Laravel 5.4]

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-backpack

I am installing Backpack package in my project, I followed the documentation steps but when I do migrate it says "Nothing to migrate".
I've already tried to publish the migrations but nothing works.

Comment: Did you add the service provider to the providers in `config/app.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their documentation, the only thing that you need to migrate is the default users and password reset table that comes with laravel.

> php artisan migrate #generates users table (using Laravel's default migrations)

So in case if you've already migrated those, then you can skip that part. But if you haven't then make sure you have the default migrations in `database/migrations` and then run `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: I deleted the users migration when I started the project, my bad.